# SPSS Questionaire - linking questions

Tags: spss

In my questionnaire I have questions which are dependent on a previously asked question and wanted to know how do I create the link between the two.

Example (just a random example created)

> Q1) What for of transport do you use to travel to work?
> -- a) Car
> -- b) Bus
> -- c) Walk
> Q2) ...
> Q3) ...
> Q4) If answered car, how many hours do you drive per day?
> -- a) 1-3hrs
> -- b) 3-6hrs
> -- c) 6+hrs
> Q5) If answered bus or walk, how long does the journey take you?
> -- a) 1-3hrs
> -- b)3-6hrs
> -- c)6+hrs

How can I make the link between Q1 and Q4 as well as Q1 and Q5, because if they answered car they will not be answering Q5 leaving the questionnaire blank.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi @spss-newbie, have you tried with producing a question before going for the merry-round?

Comment: @AndyK Yes I am able to get each question design separately

Answer (score 1):

```
If Q1="Car" TravelHours=Q4.
If any(Q1,"Bus", "Walk") TravelHours=Q5.
EXECUTE.
```